Serverless v4 - auto update concerns
I want to make sure that Serverless only runs if it's at the same version, so I've set frameworkVersion: '4.1.11'. It was working fine for a while, but suddenly, in another day, when I running serverless I spotted that Serverless was updated to '4.1.12'.
I can see that's a new "feature" on v4.
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/upgrading-v4#auto-updating
For security reasons, I only want to update Serverless when necessary.
Any suggestion how to disable it?

They realized, that auto-update is not a feasible concept and say, that they are working on a solution: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/12692

Thanks for informing me. I just subscribed to that issue to get updates.
